# Freshbooks like invoice number increment in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to create invoice number incrementing function like freshbooks. How t works in freshbooks is it increments number and alphabet both.

Condition 1:
if my invoice number is 0000012 it should be incremented to 0000013

Condition 2:
if my invoice number is 000001a it should be incremented to 000001b

and so on. 
Any idea on how to do that?

---

My attempt:

```
function replaceCharAt(string, index, character){
  return string.substr(0, index) + character + string.substr(index + character.length)
}

function generateInvoiceNumber(invoiceNumber, useIndex){
  var useIndex = useIndex || invoiceNumber.length - 1;
  var invoiceNumber = invoiceNumber.trim();
  var incrementChar = invoiceNumber[useIndex];
  if(incrementChar == '9' || incrementChar == 'z' || incrementChar == 'Z'){
    if(incrementChar == 9){
      invoiceNumber = replaceCharAt(invoiceNumber, useIndex, '0');
    }
    else{
      invoiceNumber = replaceCharAt(invoiceNumber, useIndex, 'a');
    }
    return generateInvoiceNumber(invoiceNumber, useIndex - 1);
  }
  else{
    var replaceChar = String.fromCharCode(incrementChar.charCodeAt(0) + 1);
    invoiceNumber = replaceCharAt(invoiceNumber, useIndex, replaceChar);
  }
  return invoiceNumber;
}
```

This does produce the correct results. but i am not sure about all conditions and if it will hang the event loop. I will write some test and try

Comment: Question: is this supposed to be a hexidecimal value?

Comment: Please specify the behavior. What would `000001z` be incremented to? same for `0000019` etc.

Comment: 000001z woudl be incremented to probably 000002z (have to check in freshbook how they do.) and 0000019 will increment to 0000020

Comment: 000001z was incremented to 000002a

Comment: So what would '0000029' increment to?

Comment: 0000029 would increment to 0000030 and so on

Comment: In that case at what point does a digit change from a numeric value to an alphabetic one? If incrementing 'z' results in an 'a' and incrementing '9' results in a '0' where does the changeover happen?

Comment: The character at the index before it will increment in value. I have prepared a function Will post in a while. Not sure if it is the best way

Answer (score 0):

I think I this works well now. I have tested it against most of the scenarios.

```
module.exports = {
  replaceCharAt: function replaceCharAt(string, index, character){
    var string = string.split('');
    string[index] = character;
    return string.join('');
  },
  generateInvoiceNumber: function generateInvoiceNumber(invoiceNumber, useIndex){
    var invoiceNumber = invoiceNumber.trim();
    if(typeof useIndex === 'undefined' || useIndex === -1 ){
      useIndex = invoiceNumber.length - 1;
    }
    var incrementChar = invoiceNumber[useIndex];
    if(incrementChar == '9' || incrementChar == 'z' || incrementChar == 'Z'){
      if(incrementChar == 9){
        invoiceNumber = this.replaceCharAt(invoiceNumber, useIndex, '0');
      }
      else{
        invoiceNumber = this.replaceCharAt(invoiceNumber, useIndex, 'a');
      }
      if(useIndex === 0){
        return invoiceNumber = '1'+invoiceNumber;
      }
      return this.generateInvoiceNumber(invoiceNumber, useIndex - 1);
    }
    else{
      var replaceChar = String.fromCharCode(incrementChar.charCodeAt(0) + 1);
      invoiceNumber = this.replaceCharAt(invoiceNumber, useIndex, replaceChar);
    }
    return invoiceNumber;
  }
};
```